# setting an image view in a basic UITableVewCell using NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithVisualFormat

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

I have to do this UIview subclass with out using any xib or storyboard, it needs to be 1 file so I need to get this tableview setup in code and avoid subclassing UITableViewCell.

I am trying to get an image view to be set as 
V:|-5-[imageview]-5-| and H:[iamgeview(width = height)]-5-| inside the cell's contentView.

all I get is that all my added constraint get broken and the cell is not where I want it to be.

the base cell is in basic style cell. All I am trying to do is add a image view at the end of the view and this is turning in a nightmare at the moment.

I am setting the image view as follows in the code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (!cell)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
POI *poi = [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *text = poi.name;

cell.textLabel.text = text;

UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
image.image = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:image];
NSDictionary* viewDic = @{@"image":image};
cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[image]"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:viewDic]];

[cell.contentView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[image(w)]-5-|"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:@{@"w":cell.contentView.frame.size.heigh}
                                                                            views:viewDic]];

return cell;
```

}

when the cell loads I get this error :

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb7b636aaa0 H:[img(44)]   (Names: img:0x7fb7b6368fc0 )>
```

and `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb7b6369380 V:[img(44)]   (Names: img:0x7fb7b6368fc0 )>`

and `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb7b636aaf0 H:[img]-(5)-|   (Names: Contentview:0x7fb7b6372a30, img:0x7fb7b6368fc0, '|':Contentview:0x7fb7b6372a30 )>`

and `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb7b63697e0 V:|-(5)-[img]   (Names: img:0x7fb7b6368fc0, Contentview:0x7fb7b6372a30, '|':Contentview:0x7fb7b6372a30 )>`

Comment: `image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO`

Comment: I tried this on the cell and the tableview, but I would not have taught of using it on the image it self... and it work! thank you 100000 times! I was about to go back to the old layout system! Should put that as the answer. so we can close this question.

Comment: I've added an answer with a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO` for any view on which you are using autolayout constraints. If you don't do this, autolayout constraints matching the `autoResizingMask` will be automatically added to the view *in addition to* any constraints you add manually. This will almost always result in an over-constrained view in which one or more constraints must be broken in order to layout the view.